# Kernel of homomorphism $(J:I)\rightarrow \text{Hom}_R(R/I, R/J)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

We wanted to do this:

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $I,J$ ideals of $R$. Then we have the $R$-isomorphism (of modules):
>   $$\text{Hom}_R(R/I, R/J)\cong (J:I)/J$$
>   where
>   $$(J:I)=\{x\in R\mid Ix\subseteq J\}\supseteq J$$
>   is the quotient of the ideals $J,I$.

We defined the homomorphism:
$$h:(J:I)\rightarrow \text{Hom}_R(R/I, R/J)$$
$$x\mapsto h_x$$
where
$$h_x:R/I\rightarrow R/J$$
$$r+I\mapsto xr+J$$

We proved that $h_x,h$ are homomorphisms and that $h$ is surjective, but we have trouble trying to prove that
$$\ker h=J$$

Until now we tried to do it like this:

---

Let $x\in \ker h$, then $(\forall r\in R), h_x(r+I)=0+J$, that is $xr+J=J$, and this is $xr\in J$, but we haven't been able to get further.
Any idea about this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$xr\in J$ for *all* $r\in R$, in particular for $r=1$, so $x\in J$.

Comment: Oh, that's funny. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Hom}_R(R/I, R/J) & \cong \{\varphi \in \operatorname{Hom}_R(R, R/J) : I \subseteq \ker \varphi\} \tag{1} \\
& = \{\varphi \in \operatorname{Hom}_R(R, R/J) : \varphi(a) = J \textrm{ for all } a \in I\} \\
& = \{\varphi \in \operatorname{Hom}_R(R, R/J) : a\varphi(1) = J \textrm{ for all } a \in I\} \\
& \cong \{z \in R/J : az = J \textrm{ for all } a \in I\} \tag{2} \\
& = \{x+J : x \in R \textrm{ such that } a(x+J) = J \textrm{ for all } a \in I\} \\
& = \{x+J : x \in R \textrm{ such that } ax \in J \textrm{ for all } a \in I\} \\
&= \{x + J : x \in (J : I)\} \\
&= (J : I)/J
\end{align}
where in $(1)$ we use the universal property of the quotients, and in $(2)$ we use the fact that $\operatorname{Hom}_R(R,M) \cong M$ for any $R$-module $M$ via $\varphi \mapsto \varphi(1)$.