# The homomorphism $h:(J:I)\rightarrow \text{Hom}_R(R/I,R/J)$ is surjective.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

We've got [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1441479/kernel-of-homomorphism-ji-rightarrow-texthom-rr-i-r-j) homomorphism 
$$h:(J:I)\rightarrow \text{Hom}_R(R/I, R/J)$$
$$x\mapsto h_x$$
where
$$h_x:R/I\rightarrow R/J$$
$$r+I\mapsto xr+J.$$

We found a mistake in the proof of the surjectivity... I thought about this workaround, but it seems too unconventional and I'm not sure it's correct.

Let $m\in \text{Hom}_R(R/I, R/J)$, and given that define $m'\subseteq R\times R$ such that $xm'y$ iff $m(x+I)=y+J$.
We first show that if $xm'y$ then for any $\alpha\in R, (\alpha x)m'(\alpha y)$.

So
 $$m(\alpha x+I)=\alpha m(x+I)=\alpha (x+J)=\alpha x+J$$
and indeed $(\alpha x)m'(\alpha y)$.

Now let $u$ such that $1m'u$. Then:

$$h_u (x+I)=ux+J=m(1x+I)=m(x+I).$$

Excluding that (I just noticed this) I have no guarantee (for now) that $u\in (J:I)$, is the attempt of proof wrong? In that case, is there any way to fix it? Is there a more conventional way to prove it? In case the attempt of proof is mostly correct, how can I find some of these $u$ in $(J:I)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're making things too complicate. `;-)`

Let $f\colon R/I\to R/J$ be a homomorphism. Consider the composition map $g=f\circ \pi\colon R\to R/J$ and write $g(1)=x+J$. Then, for every $r\in R$, $g(r)=g(1r)=g(1)r=xr+J$.

Since $g(r)=0$, for every $r\in I$, we know that $xI\subseteq J$, so that $x\in (J\mathbin:I)$.

Now, $h_x(r+I)=xr+J=g(1)r=g(r)=f\circ\pi(r)=f(r+I)$, so $h_x=f$.

Answer (score 1):

$u\in(J:I)$ since for $a\in I$ we have: $m(1+I)=u+J\Rightarrow am(1+I)=a(u+J)\Rightarrow m(a+I)=au+J\Rightarrow 0+J=au+J$, so $au\in J$.